# How to enable Shadow Copy for current app domain

Tags: asp.net, shadow

I have a service which uses multiple dlls using reflection method . These dlls are loaded dynamically but once window service runs i am not able to update the dll or delete them etc .

I see Shadow copying as a viable solution . but i cannot find exact syntax if i want to set ShadowCopyfiles property of current appdomain to true.

I am using asp.net , and framework is 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/02/09/69919.aspx) to setting it up, hope that helps.